# Program causes OSX (Snow Leopard 10.6.4) window server to spontaneously crash

Tags: python, cocoa, macos, opengl, osx-snow-leopard

I have a program that uses OpenGL combined with Cocoa and Python using PyObjC.

I've recently expanded on my menu making code to show menu selections for maps including map information. When using the new code, the window server will spontaneously crash at some random point (Not random but it appears that way). The new code uses nothing radical. It's using the same graphics code as everything else. I don't know where to look.

Can anyone make sense of this crash report from the console application?

```
Process:         WindowServer [775]
Path:            /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Versions/A/Resources/WindowServer
Identifier:      WindowServer
Version:         ??? (???)
Code Type:       X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [1]

Date/Time:       2010-08-04 16:02:03.861 +0100
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.6.4 (10F569)
Report Version:  6

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000000
Crashed Thread:  0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Thread 0 Crashed:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   com.apple.GeForceGLDriver       0x00000002000119a4 gldAttachDrawable + 2388
1   com.apple.GeForceGLDriver       0x00000002000ce0c5 gldUpdateDispatch + 14581
2   com.apple.GeForceGLDriver       0x00000002000ce1b6 gldUpdateDispatch + 14822
3   GLEngine                        0x000000011221f146 glFlush_Exec + 133
4   com.apple.CoreGraphics          0x00007fff802bc177 CGXGLAccelFinish + 154
5   com.apple.CoreGraphics          0x00007fff802bb2e0 CGXReleaseDisplayDeviceSurface + 232
6   com.apple.CoreGraphics          0x00007fff80469c02 CGXRedrawSpecifiedWindowsToDisplayAndRegion + 3663
7   com.apple.CoreGraphics          0x00007fff802afb42 CGXUpdateMagicMirror + 641
8   com.apple.CoreGraphics          0x00007fff8029092e CGXUpdateDisplay + 1308
9   com.apple.CoreGraphics          0x00007fff8045cbc2 CGXFlushSurface + 732
10  com.apple.CoreGraphics          0x00007fff8048440d _CGXFlushSurfaceInline + 231
11  com.apple.CoreGraphics          0x00007fff803f366c _XFlushSurfaceInline + 205
12  com.apple.CoreGraphics          0x00007fff802c31cd CGXServices_server + 108
13  com.apple.CoreGraphics          0x00007fff802c2e8a connectionHandler + 220
14  com.apple.CoreGraphics          0x00007fff802a4f2d CGXPostPortData + 175
15  com.apple.CoreGraphics          0x00007fff802a4d37 CGXRunOneServerPass + 451
16  com.apple.CoreGraphics          0x00007fff802a1e4d CGXRunOneServicesPass + 672
17  com.apple.CoreGraphics          0x00007fff802aad4a CGXServerLoop + 139
18  com.apple.CoreGraphics          0x00007fff80275856 CGXGetRootAdminCredentials + 0
19  WindowServer                    0x0000000100000f29 main + 9
20  WindowServer                    0x0000000100000f18 start + 52

Thread 1:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff88c7408a kevent + 10
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff88c75f5d _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 154
2   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff88c75c34 _dispatch_queue_invoke + 185
3   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff88c7575e _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 252
4   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff88c75088 _pthread_wqthread + 353
5   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff88c74f25 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 2:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff88c5b2fa mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff88c5b96d mach_msg + 59
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff846173c2 __CFRunLoopRun + 1698
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8461684f CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 575
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff846165d6 CFRunLoopRun + 70
5   com.apple.CoreGraphics          0x00007fff8028773e eventThread + 470
6   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff88c94456 _pthread_start + 331
7   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff88c94309 thread_start + 13

Thread 3:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff88c5b2fa mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff88c5b96d mach_msg + 59
2   com.apple.QuartzCore            0x00007fff8317abe2 CA::Render::Server::server_thread(void*) + 177
3   com.apple.QuartzCore            0x00007fff8317ab22 thread_fun + 34
4   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff88c94456 _pthread_start + 331
5   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff88c94309 thread_start + 13

Thread 4:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff88c95eb6 __semwait_signal + 10
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff88c99cd1 _pthread_cond_wait + 1286
2   com.apple.CoreGraphics          0x00007fff8036082a layer_blit_work_queue_thread + 714
3   com.apple.CoreGraphics          0x00007fff80360a9c layer_blit_work_queue_server + 156
4   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff88c94456 _pthread_start + 331
5   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff88c94309 thread_start + 13

Thread 0 crashed with X86 Thread State (64-bit):
  rax: 0x00000000e00002c2  rbx: 0x0000000112414000  rcx: 0x00007fff88c5b2fa  rdx: 0x0000000012457000
  rdi: 0x00007fff5fbed310  rsi: 0x00007fff711475c0  rbp: 0x00007fff5fbee4a0  rsp: 0x00007fff5fbee4a0
   r8: 0x0000000000000e03   r9: 0x0000000000000000  r10: 0x00000000000010bc  r11: 0x0000000000000206
  r12: 0x0000000112457000  r13: 0x0000000000000003  r14: 0x00007fff5fbee4d0  r15: 0x00000001001c6430
  rip: 0x00000002000119a4  rfl: 0x0000000000010246  cr2: 0x0000000000000000

Binary Images:
       0x100000000 -        0x100000fff  WindowServer ??? (???) <339853D7-1BCB-51F6-24DA-7615FFB3DDEB> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/WindowServer
       0x100583000 -        0x100597fff  com.apple.GeForceGA 1.6.16 (6.1.6) <5D2C7F65-FF94-5808-AFFB-18DC4BED0C58> /System/Library/Extensions/GeForceGA.plugin/Contents/MacOS/GeForceGA
       0x112200000 -        0x11238dfe7  GLEngine ??? (???) <57D733C2-F7CB-2B8F-CD34-C85A193145DE> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Resources/GLEngine.bundle/GLEngine
       0x113000000 -        0x113423fef  libclh.dylib 3.1.1 C  (3.1.1) <83F3C7DB-D2E2-07B0-E433-386C9428AD72> /System/Library/Extensions/GeForceGLDriver.bundle/Contents/MacOS/libclh.dylib
       0x200000000 -        0x2006fbff7  com.apple.GeForceGLDriver 1.6.16 (6.1.6) <4F3D3917-641B-AA12-04DE-D3A1995C3B18> /System/Library/Extensions/GeForceGLDriver.bundle/Contents/MacOS/GeForceGLDriver
    0x7fff5fc00000 -     0x7fff5fc3bdef  dyld 132.1 (???) <B536F2F1-9DF1-3B6C-1C2C-9075EA219A06> /usr/lib/dyld
    0x7fff80003000 -     0x7fff80005fff  libRadiance.dylib ??? (???) <D67C08B6-4D4A-916D-E936-528E145A56E2> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libRadiance.dylib
    0x7fff80006000 -     0x7fff80096fff  com.apple.SearchKit 1.3.0 (1.3.0) <4175DC31-1506-228A-08FD-C704AC9DF642> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/SearchKit.framework/Versions/A/SearchKit
    0x7fff800d6000 -     0x7fff8011eff7  libvDSP.dylib 268.0.1 (compatibility 1.0.0) <170DE04F-89AB-E295-0880-D69CAFBD7979> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libvDSP.dylib
    0x7fff801ba000 -     0x7fff808b7067  com.apple.CoreGraphics 1.543.50 (???) <46A7D60C-0500-B96C-ECAD-1D658487D213> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Versions/A/CoreGraphics
    0x7fff80c60000 -     0x7fff80d30ff7  com.apple.CFNetwork 454.9.7 (454.9.7) <AA6EB690-6CCF-603D-AAC2-35B9E05D1593> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/Versions/A/CFNetwork
    0x7fff80d31000 -     0x7fff80d45ff7  com.apple.speech.synthesis.framework 3.10.35 (3.10.35) <621B7415-A0B9-07A7-F313-36BEEDD7B132> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/SpeechSynthesis.framework/Versions/A/SpeechSynthesis
    0x7fff80d46000 -     0x7fff80d4cff7  com.apple.DiskArbitration 2.3 (2.3) <857F6E43-1EF4-7D53-351B-10DE0A8F992A> /System/Library/Frameworks/DiskArbitration.framework/Versions/A/DiskArbitration
    0x7fff81307000 -     0x7fff81356fef  libTIFF.dylib ??? (???) <A66CBA9C-A38D-5EDB-BFB5-CB398F033D6F> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libTIFF.dylib
    0x7fff81412000 -     0x7fff8143dff7  libxslt.1.dylib 3.24.0 (compatibility 3.0.0) <87A0B228-B24A-C426-C3FB-B40D7258DD49> /usr/lib/libxslt.1.dylib
    0x7fff816ea000 -     0x7fff816fbff7  libz.1.dylib 1.2.3 (compatibility 1.0.0) <FB5EE53A-0534-0FFA-B2ED-486609433717> /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib
    0x7fff816fc000 -     0x7fff816fcff7  com.apple.CoreServices 44 (44) <210A4C56-BECB-E3E4-B6EE-7EC53E02265D> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/CoreServices
    0x7fff8189e000 -     0x7fff8189fff7  com.apple.TrustEvaluationAgent 1.1 (1) <51867586-1C71-AE37-EAAD-535A58DD3550> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/TrustEvaluationAgent.framework/Versions/A/TrustEvaluationAgent
    0x7fff818a3000 -     0x7fff818b7fff  libGL.dylib ??? (???) <5AD69545-D1A3-C017-C7AF-B4AFD6F08FA2> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/Libraries/libGL.dylib
    0x7fff818b8000 -     0x7fff81a6efef  com.apple.ImageIO.framework 3.0.3 (3.0.3) <A32D0B5A-7149-7739-22D3-84D38B07E9E5> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/ImageIO
    0x7fff81c95000 -     0x7fff81c9bff7  IOSurface ??? (???) <EB2019F6-7C5C-3D59-E11F-6119466C12A9> /System/Library/Frameworks/IOSurface.framework/Versions/A/IOSurface
    0x7fff81ce0000 -     0x7fff82013fe7  com.apple.CoreServices.CarbonCore 861.13 (861.13) <BC2F9B4E-D305-D717-D97E-EC78C7DE9EE9> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/CarbonCore.framework/Versions/A/CarbonCore
    0x7fff82014000 -     0x7fff82091fef  libstdc++.6.dylib 7.9.0 (compatibility 7.0.0) <35ECA411-2C08-FD7D-11B1-1B7A04921A5C> /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib
    0x7fff82092000 -     0x7fff82097fff  libGFXShared.dylib ??? (???) <1265FAEF-1C97-B339-28A4-4510589B067B> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/Libraries/libGFXShared.dylib
    0x7fff82a87000 -     0x7fff82a9dfef  libbsm.0.dylib ??? (???) <42D3023A-A1F7-4121-6417-FCC6B51B3E90> /usr/lib/libbsm.0.dylib
    0x7fff82ac5000 -     0x7fff82c83fff  libicucore.A.dylib 40.0.0 (compatibility 1.0.0) <0E53A4A6-AC06-1B61-2285-248F534EE356> /usr/lib/libicucore.A.dylib
    0x7fff82ea3000 -     0x7fff82ea3ff7  com.apple.Accelerate 1.6 (Accelerate 1.6) <2BB7D669-4B40-6A52-ADBD-DA4DB3BC0B1B> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Accelerate
    0x7fff82ec5000 -     0x7fff82ec5ff7  com.apple.ApplicationServices 38 (38) <10A0B9E9-4988-03D4-FC56-DDE231A02C63> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/ApplicationServices
    0x7fff83060000 -     0x7fff83120fff  libFontParser.dylib ??? (???) <A4F8189D-1D5B-2F8D-E78E-6D934A8E8407> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ATS.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libFontParser.dylib
    0x7fff83121000 -     0x7fff83125ff7  libmathCommon.A.dylib 315.0.0 (compatibility 1.0.0) <95718673-FEEE-B6ED-B127-BCDBDB60D4E5> /usr/lib/system/libmathCommon.A.dylib
    0x7fff83128000 -     0x7fff834c1ff7  com.apple.QuartzCore 1.6.2 (227.22) <76EE0A32-B20B-F316-ADDD-4230329253D5> /System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/Versions/A/QuartzCore
    0x7fff83612000 -     0x7fff8361ffe7  libCSync.A.dylib 543.50.0 (compatibility 64.0.0) <7B891D4C-1F19-4DB0-FD12-7A7D5E8F47AE> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libCSync.A.dylib
    0x7fff836a4000 -     0x7fff836cafe7  libJPEG.dylib ??? (???) <4060F3E2-BAD3-244F-D777-51BA16569DA4> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libJPEG.dylib
    0x7fff836cb000 -     0x7fff837e2fef  libxml2.2.dylib 10.3.0 (compatibility 10.0.0) <EE067D7E-15B3-F043-6FBD-10BA31FE76C7> /usr/lib/libxml2.2.dylib
    0x7fff83851000 -     0x7fff83860fff  com.apple.NetFS 3.2.1 (3.2.1) <FF21DB1E-F425-1005-FB70-BC19CAF4006E> /System/Library/Frameworks/NetFS.framework/Versions/A/NetFS
    0x7fff83ae2000 -     0x7fff83b40ff7  com.apple.framework.IOKit 2.0 (???) <010C3398-7363-8F4B-719C-263867F15F63> /System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Versions/A/IOKit
    0x7fff83bb5000 -     0x7fff83c8fff7  com.apple.vImage 4.0 (4.0) <354F34BF-B221-A3C9-2CA7-9BE5E14AD5AD> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vImage.framework/Versions/A/vImage
    0x7fff83e01000 -     0x7fff83e52fe7  com.apple.HIServices 1.8.0 (???) <1ABA7802-C1E4-06A0-9035-2792CC915BF6> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/HIServices.framework/Versions/A/HIServices
    0x7fff83e53000 -     0x7fff83e61ff7  libkxld.dylib ??? (???) <EE840168-1F67-6219-8BA3-C46039BCC8B3> /usr/lib/system/libkxld.dylib
    0x7fff83e6f000 -     0x7fff83eb9ff7  com.apple.Metadata 10.6.3 (507.10) <641395B7-FF2C-B94C-965A-CE6A0830645F> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/Metadata.framework/Versions/A/Metadata
    0x7fff8403a000 -     0x7fff840bffff  com.apple.print.framework.PrintCore 6.2 (312.5) <E736F6DC-2E69-A14D-6BCF-69D14232F8B8> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/PrintCore.framework/Versions/A/PrintCore
    0x7fff840dc000 -     0x7fff84195fff  libsqlite3.dylib 9.6.0 (compatibility 9.0.0) <5A15E12A-AE8F-1A36-BBC7-564E7D7AD0FB> /usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib
    0x7fff841d9000 -     0x7fff84273fff  com.apple.ApplicationServices.ATS 4.3 (???) <A7CD9E1F-C563-E940-130D-AA7E08C5A29F> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ATS.framework/Versions/A/ATS
    0x7fff84274000 -     0x7fff84289ff7  com.apple.LangAnalysis 1.6.6 (1.6.6) <DC999B32-BF41-94C8-0583-27D9AB463E8B> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/LangAnalysis.framework/Versions/A/LangAnalysis
    0x7fff845cb000 -     0x7fff84740ff7  com.apple.CoreFoundation 6.6.3 (550.29) <48810602-63C3-994D-E563-DD02B16E76E1> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation
    0x7fff84741000 -     0x7fff84762fff  libresolv.9.dylib 41.0.0 (compatibility 1.0.0) <6993F348-428F-C97E-7A84-7BD2EDC46A62> /usr/lib/libresolv.9.dylib
    0x7fff84763000 -     0x7fff84818fe7  com.apple.ColorSync 4.6.3 (4.6.3) <AA93AD96-6974-9104-BF55-AF7A813C8A1B> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ColorSync.framework/Versions/A/ColorSync
    0x7fff84819000 -     0x7fff848d6ff7  com.apple.CoreServices.OSServices 357 (357) <718F0719-DC9F-E392-7C64-9D7DFE3D02E2> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/OSServices.framework/Versions/A/OSServices
    0x7fff848d7000 -     0x7fff84977fff  com.apple.LaunchServices 362.1 (362.1) <2740103A-6C71-D99F-8C6F-FA264546AD8F> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/LaunchServices.framework/Versions/A/LaunchServices
    0x7fff84978000 -     0x7fff849b0fef  libcups.2.dylib 2.8.0 (compatibility 2.0.0) <31A78904-A500-0DA9-0609-F1EB81383326> /usr/lib/libcups.2.dylib
    0x7fff84a39000 -     0x7fff84a3efff  libGIF.dylib ??? (???) <21FC6B02-6AC3-C4DB-0B50-98144802274C> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libGIF.dylib
    0x7fff84b1b000 -     0x7fff84f5efef  libLAPACK.dylib 219.0.0 (compatibility 1.0.0) <0CC61C98-FF51-67B3-F3D8-C5E430C201A9> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libLAPACK.dylib
    0x7fff84f5f000 -     0x7fff84f82fff  com.apple.opencl 12.1 (12.1) <403E8F37-4348-B9BC-08E6-7693A995B7EC> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenCL.framework/Versions/A/OpenCL
    0x7fff84f83000 -     0x7fff84fa8fe7  com.apple.CoreVideo 1.6.1 (45.4) <B1516554-88BC-CF1E-5409-BFF27A73D1AF> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreVideo.framework/Versions/A/CoreVideo
    0x7fff8532f000 -     0x7fff8533eff7  com.apple.opengl 1.6.8 (1.6.8) <0CDC4F98-7981-A114-1778-AF171075138E> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/OpenGL
    0x7fff85364000 -     0x7fff85382fff  libPng.dylib ??? (???) <F6932C8D-E6B1-0871-B698-15180AA948F7> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libPng.dylib
    0x7fff855a6000 -     0x7fff85827fef  com.apple.Foundation 6.6.3 (751.29) <DAEDB589-9F59-9556-CF8D-07556317937B> /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Versions/C/Foundation
    0x7fff8587b000 -     0x7fff858a3fff  com.apple.DictionaryServices 1.1.1 (1.1.1) <9FD709FC-23F0-F270-EAC1-C590CD516A36> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/DictionaryServices.framework/Versions/A/DictionaryServices
    0x7fff8594d000 -     0x7fff85a5cfe7  libcrypto.0.9.8.dylib 0.9.8 (compatibility 0.9.8) <36DA89A6-3AF5-86F2-BDD5-B94C7C0844D4> /usr/lib/libcrypto.0.9.8.dylib
    0x7fff86770000 -     0x7fff869f6ff7  com.apple.security 6.1.1 (37594) <5EDDC08C-C95B-2D24-E1D2-D30D233AB065> /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security
    0x7fff87514000 -     0x7fff8754ffff  com.apple.AE 496.4 (496.4) <CBEDB6A1-FD85-F842-4EB8-CC289FAE0F24> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/AE.framework/Versions/A/AE
    0x7fff87558000 -     0x7fff8755bff7  libCoreVMClient.dylib ??? (???) <DBB2C09F-4BF4-326C-B775-B7A128C501E3> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/Libraries/libCoreVMClient.dylib
    0x7fff87774000 -     0x7fff877bdfef  libGLU.dylib ??? (???) <34D118CD-F9EE-D023-FEBF-74581DEF31CD> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/Libraries/libGLU.dylib
    0x7fff87d7f000 -     0x7fff87e2efff  edu.mit.Kerberos 6.5.10 (6.5.10) <F3F76EDF-5660-78F0-FE6E-33B6174F55A4> /System/Library/Frameworks/Kerberos.framework/Versions/A/Kerberos
    0x7fff87e2f000 -     0x7fff87e70fff  com.apple.SystemConfiguration 1.10.2 (1.10.2) <BC27BDD4-9CC8-9AF0-B4C2-DD50FD751CBF> /System/Library/Frameworks/SystemConfiguration.framework/Versions/A/SystemConfiguration
    0x7fff87fef000 -     0x7fff87ff5fff  libCGXCoreImage.A.dylib 543.50.0 (compatibility 64.0.0) <2D72D55A-C8FE-78DD-602E-E934057EDF95> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libCGXCoreImage.A.dylib
    0x7fff88208000 -     0x7fff88a12fe7  libBLAS.dylib 219.0.0 (compatibility 1.0.0) <FC941ECB-71D0-FAE3-DCBF-C5A619E594B8> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBLAS.dylib
    0x7fff88a13000 -     0x7fff88b2cfef  libGLProgrammability.dylib ??? (???) <B057FC52-6A97-F450-48D8-325A70423A53> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/Libraries/libGLProgrammability.dylib
    0x7fff88b68000 -     0x7fff88c1efff  libobjc.A.dylib 227.0.0 (compatibility 1.0.0) <F206BE6D-8777-AE6C-B367-7BEA76C14241> /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
    0x7fff88c59000 -     0x7fff88c59ff7  com.apple.Accelerate.vecLib 3.6 (vecLib 3.6) <DA9BFF01-40DF-EBD5-ABB7-787DAF2D77CF> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/vecLib
    0x7fff88c5a000 -     0x7fff88e1afef  libSystem.B.dylib 125.2.0 (compatibility 1.0.0) <95E02DD0-ADEA-745B-E7FA-ABA064E4658C> /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
    0x7fff88e1b000 -     0x7fff88e85fe7  libvMisc.dylib 268.0.1 (compatibility 1.0.0) <75A8D840-4ACE-6560-0889-2AFB6BE08E59> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libvMisc.dylib
    0x7fff88eaa000 -     0x7fff88ef6fff  libauto.dylib ??? (???) <072804DF-36AD-2DBE-7EF8-639CFB79077F> /usr/lib/libauto.dylib
    0x7fff88ef7000 -     0x7fff88f38fef  com.apple.QD 3.35 (???) <78C9A560-E6F7-DC4F-F85E-E63CF8A98F0B> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/QD.framework/Versions/A/QD
    0x7fff88fb6000 -     0x7fff88fe7fff  libGLImage.dylib ??? (???) <2F18DB77-CF77-1311-9E20-FE460090C166> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/Libraries/libGLImage.dylib
    0x7fff88fe8000 -     0x7fff89066fff  com.apple.CoreText 3.1.0 (???) <B740DA1D-EFD0-CCBF-F893-E3004FE58A98> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/CoreText.framework/Versions/A/CoreText
    0x7fffffe00000 -     0x7fffffe01fff  libSystem.B.dylib ??? (???) <95E02DD0-ADEA-745B-E7FA-ABA064E4658C> /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is NOT a new "bug" by any means. Doing a search turns up a number of instances over the years.

I have two servers, one Panther (10.3.9) & the other Tiger (10.4.11) that present this error when doing certain actions, neither of them the same action but similar. I suspect that something else is causing the graphics to crash, maybe bad property list or ? The Panther one is ALWAYS something to do w/cursor display.

Comment: Hmmm. Hopefully it will get resolved. I was going to convert the game to Objective-C but then I decided to forget about the game entirely. The source code is available here -> http://godofgod.co.uk/my_files/Public%20source%20code.zip

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, there's nothing you can do about it unfortunately. It's a crash introduced with 10.6.4 by Apple.

Comment: It might not be my fault but there must be a way around it because the rest of my game works.

Another part of my menu just added also causes this to happen but beforehand the fps drops considerably before the crash happens. For the map selection part of the menu, no fps drop is noticeable.

Comment: Can you reference a bug report to confirm your statement?